# Avoid Duplicate Posts In 3 Wordpress Loops

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, duplicates

I have the following code as the header block of 3 articles on my website's homepage and category pages. However, it loads the same post 3 times. I've seen multiple answers on how to prevent duplicate posts but unfortunately, I couldn't get them to work with my code below and I'm a bit new when it comes to this. Would someone be able to help re-write it so that it calls 3 different posts?

```
div class="content-block-header">

    <div class="content-block-header-1">

        <div class="content-block-header-thumbnail-1">
            <a href="<?php
the_permalink();
?>"><?php
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array(
    'class' => 'alignleft'
));
?></a>
        </div>

        <div class="content-block-header-meta-1">
        <h2 class="content-block-header-title-1"><a href="<?php
the_permalink();
?>"><?php
the_title();
?></a></h2>

        <div class="content-block-header-author-1"> <?php
the_author_posts_link();
?> | <?php
echo get_the_date();
?> </div>
        </div>

</div>




        <div class="content-block-header-2">
    <div class="content-block-header-thumbnail-2">
            <a href="<?php
the_permalink();
?>"><?php
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array(
    'class' => 'alignleft'
));
?></a>
    </div>

    <div class="content-block-header-meta-2">
        <h2 class="content-block-header-title-2"><a href="<?php
the_permalink();
?>"><?php
the_title();
?></a></h2>

<div class="content-block-header-author-2"> <?php
the_author_posts_link();
?> | <?php
echo get_the_date();
?> </div>
    </div>

</div>




        <div class="content-block-header-3">
    <div class="content-block-header-thumbnail-3">
            <a href="<?php
the_permalink();
?>"><?php
echo get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id, 'large', array(
    'class' => 'alignleft'
));
?></a>
    </div>

    <div class="content-block-header-meta-3">
        <h2 class="content-block-header-title-3"><a href="<?php
the_permalink();
?>"><?php
the_title();
?></a></h2>

<div class="content-block-header-author-3"> <?php
the_author_posts_link();
?> | <?php
echo get_the_date();
?> </div>
    </div>

</div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Couple questions.  Just want to make sure I understand the scope here.  You have 3 posts, and you want to get them, and display them on a page, correct?  Or is this like 3 different pages and you want the particular page to show a different header?

Comment: The same page. I use Display Posts (displayposts.com) to call two shortcodes on the homepage and category page. The first shortcode calls the template part above, creating a featured "block" of 3 articles. The second shortcode just calls a list of recent articles.